# C++ image processing, counting particles

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I'd like to count the number of particles in images.
I've found ImageJ doing exactly what i need http://imagej.net/Particle_Analysis but it's Java and it's just one of the features i need to integrate, making it worthless to call the Java program from my C++ application.
I'm searching for a C++ library that implements this, any comprehensive algorithm is more than welcome. 
All the best

Answer (score 2):

I think **CImg** would be a great solution for you - it is [here](http://cimg.eu). It is single C++ header file - no libraries or anything to link and it runs on just about any platform - Linux, OS X, Windows.

The function you need is `label()`. Here is a short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    CImg<int> img("input.png");
    img.label(0,0);
    img.save_png("result.png");
}
```

I made a test image with **ImageMagick** like this at the command line:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:black -fill white \
  -draw "rectangle 10,10 50,50"              \
  -draw "rectangle 100,200 300,400"          \
  -draw "rectangle 800,25 900,900" input.png
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Then, when you run the program it labels each blob (i.e. rectangle) with an increasing number, i.e. each one is a bit brighter than the last.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

have a look at openCV http://opencv.org/. They have a plethora of functions and algorithms related to computer vision. Depending on the shape and structure of the particles in your image the SimpleBlobDetector() may or may not be usefull. There is a good tutorial here: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/.

Alternativly you could try implement your own algorithm? Have a search for Laplacian of Gaussian kernel. If your particles are an irregular shape, it may become more difficult and require thresholding and contoring.

Comment: thanks your your feedback, yes the image are from space imagery. Each time i think about OpenCV i think about its size, it becomes huge over years. SimpleBlobDetector looks to be what i'm looking for, thank you so much. Of course the original image need some cleanup (removing the irregular background, incraesing the contrast etc).